# Why is the category of coherent sheaves not grothendieck?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, sheaf-theory

Let $(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ be a ringed space.  It is well-known that the category $\mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{O}_X)$ of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules is a *grothendieck* abelian category (see e.g. Grothendieck's Tohoku paper).  When $X$ is a scheme, the full subcategory $\mathbf{Qcoh}(\mathscr{O}_X)$ of quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules is also grothendieck abelian (even if $X$ is not quasi-compact and quasi-separated, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39941/does-qcohx-admit-a-generating-set)).

Now consider the full subcategory $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathscr{O}_X) \subset \mathbf{Mod}(\mathscr{O}_X)$ of *coherent* $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules.  This is an exact abelian subcategory but is *not*, in general, grothendieck.  My first question is: why not?

> Intuitively speaking, why is $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathscr{O}_X)$ not grothendieck abelian?  What goes wrong?

Secondly, can the situation be rescued?

> Are there assumptions on $X$, e.g. noetherian, or proper over a noetherian base, etc., under which $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathscr{O}_X)$ is grothendieck abelian?

Any reference that addresses these or related questions is very welcome.

Comment: I don't know much about sheaves, but I wonder: Is $\mathbf{Coh}(\mathscr{O}_X)$ ever complete/cocomplete?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The category of coherent sheaves is almost never a Grothendieck abelian category, but for essentially trivial reasons:

1. The category of coherent sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec} A$, where $A$ is a noetherian ring, is equivalent to the category of finitely generated (= finitely presented) $A$-modules.
2. The category of finitely presented $A$-modules is almost never cocomplete, simply because the direct sum of infinitely many finitely presented $A$-modules is almost never a finitely presented $A$-module!
3. Grothendieck abelian categories are, by definition, cocomplete.

Of course, I have to keep saying "almost" because there is in fact an example of a scheme for which the category of coherent sheaves is a Grothendieck abelian category: the empty scheme $\emptyset$. But this scheme has some rather bizarre properties; for instance, every sheaf is automatically quasi-coherent, coherent, and even free...

Comment: It is clear that the direct sum *as modules* of infinitely many f.p. $A$-modules is not f.p. But why is it the case that this really should be the coproduct?

Comment: You can check it by applying $\mathrm{Hom}_A (-, A)$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks!